# Создать график в matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Мне требуется создать график, используя следующие данные из файла csv:

> **x** - года, **y** - значения.

Проблема в том, что в файле каждый из годов имеет по **52** разных значения, а не 1.
Что мне делать в таком случае?

Пример файла:

```
1981, 1,
1981, 2,
1981, 3,
...
1981, 52,
1982, 1 (и так далее)
```

Как я могу построить график, используя все **52** точки 1го года, но при этом на оси `x` отобразить год только 1 рза? Вот, какой результат я ожидаю увидеть:

[image: 1]
Вот, что имею:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходный код:\

```
    def GETVALUES(self):
        value1 = self.comboBox.currentText()
        value2 = self.comboBox_2.currentText()
        value3 = self.comboBox_3.currentText()
        print(value1)
        print(value2)
        print(value3)

        self.initUX(value1)

    def initNames(self):
        provinces = (
            "cherkassy", "chernihiv", "chernivtsi", "crimea", "dnipropetrovsk", "donetsk", "ivano-fr", "kharkiv",
            "kherson", "khmelnytsky", "kiev", "kiev-city", "kirovohrad", "luhansk", "lviv", "mykolaiv", "odessa",
            "poltava",
            "rivne", "sevastopol", "sumy", "ternopil", "transcarpatia", "vinnytsya", "volyn", "zaporizhia",
            "zhytomyr")
        return provinces

    def initUX(self, provinceN):
        value2 = self.comboBox_2.currentText()
        value3 = self.comboBox_3.currentText()
        A = (int)(value2)
        B = (int)(value3)
        c = (A - 1981) * 52
        d = ((B - A)  * 52)
        data = pd.read_csv("C://Users//vladi//PycharmProjects//pythonProject//venv//vhi_id_" +
                           provinceN + ".csv",skiprows=c,nrows=d, index_col=False, header=None)
        df = data

        return df

    def getYears(self):
        D = ("1981","1982","1983","1984","1985","1986","1987","1988","1989","1990","1991","1992","1993","1994","1995",
             "1996","1997","1998","1999","2000","2001","2002","2003","2004","2005","2006","2007","2008","2009","2010",
             "2011","2012","2013","2014","2015","2016","2017","2018","2019","2020","2021")
        return D

    def createGraphh(self):
        value1 = self.comboBox.currentText()
        value2 = self.comboBox_2.currentText()
        value3 = self.comboBox_3.currentText()
        A = (int)(value2)
        B = (int)(value3)
        c = (A - 1981) * 52
        d = ((B - A) * 52)

        df = self.initUX(value1)


        #xxx = np.arange(int(value2), int(value3), 1)
        data = {value1: df[6]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        x = np.arange((B - A) * 52)
        plt.axis([0, 52*(B - A), 0, 100])

        plt.grid()
        #print(dd[0])


        ax = plt.gca()
        plt.draw()

        ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(), rotation=45)
        plt.axhspan(0, 15, facecolor='#A12020', alpha=0.5)
        plt.axhspan(15, 35, facecolor='#D78352', alpha=0.5)
        plt.axhspan(35, 60, facecolor='#B4D64E', alpha=0.5)
        plt.axhspan(60, 100, facecolor='#3DE11C', alpha=0.5)

        k = df.max(axis=0,skipna = True)
        plt.plot(x, df, '-r')
        plt.legend(data, loc=2)
        plt.show()
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос воспроизводимый пример исходных данных и свой код.

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поскольку как вас просили минимально воспроизводимого примера от вас мы так и не дождались, набирать в ручную пример с 40 годами и 52 (очевидно неделями) в году - как то особого желания нет, привожу игрушечный пример, который покажет то, что вы собственно просили  - *"Как  построить график, используя все .. точки 1го года, но при этом **на оси x отобразить год только 1 раз**?"*
Вот как-то так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import pandas as pd
fig,ax = plt.subplots()
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1981,1981,1981,
                      1982,1982,1982,
                      1983,1983,1983,
                      1984,1984,1984],
                 'B':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3],
                 'C':[1,3,2,4,5,4,3,5,6,9,11,8]})
ax.plot(df.index,df.C)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.IndexLocator(3,0))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
ax.set_xticklabels(df.A[::3])
```

И получите что-то примерно такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь тюнингуйте этот пример "под себя".